# Using .toUpperCase to check for upper-caseness

Tags: javascript

My program replaces word 'before' with word 'after' in a string. I think that I might be using .toUpperCase and .toLowerCase in the wrong way. Can I use .toUpperCase to *check for* upper-caseness, or can I only use it to *assign* upper-caseness? I have posted my short program. It is thoroughly commented with how I expect it to work, and then with the expected result and actual result.

```
// Params are string, word to be removed, new word to replace removed word.
function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  var afterCap;
  var newString;

  // Uppercase first letter of after, add rest of word.
  // afterCap is then capitalized after.
  afterCap = after[0].toUpperCase() + after.slice(1);

  // If before is capitalized,
  if (before[0].toUpperCase()) {
    // Replace with capitalized after.
    newString = str.replace(before, afterCap);
  }

  // If before not-capitalized,
  else if (before[0].toLowerCase()) {
    // Replace with lowercase after.
    newString = str.replace(before, after);
  }

  console.log(newString);
}

myReplace("Let us go to the store", "store", "mall");

// Should return "Let us go to the mall"
// Is in fact returning "Let us go to the Mall"
```

Why is the lower-case word 'store' being replaced with the upper case 'Mall'?

Comment: You seem to know that `toUpperCase()` returns a string, because you do `afterCap = after[0].toUpperCase() + after.slice(1);`. But here you use it as a test: `if (before[0].toUpperCase())`. What do you think `toUpperCase` returns here?

Comment: If you only use `afterCap` in the `if` part but not in the `else`, then assign the value inside the `if`, not before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**toUppercase returns a string, not a boolean**

Your code isn't actually checking if the first letter is upper case or not, just translating them to uppercase and checking if truthy. if the string is non-empty then **the result will be truthy, and the *first block* will be executed**, if it is empty **the result will be an empty string, which is falsy, and *nothing* will be executed**

Truthy values in javascript are all values **except** for **false, 0, null, undefined and NaN** see the MDN article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) for more information

Change this

```
// If before is capitalized,
if (before[0].toUpperCase()) {
// Replace with capitalized after.
    newString = str.replace(before, afterCap);
}
```

to this

```
// If before is capitalized,
if (before[0].toUpperCase() === before[0]) {
// Replace with capitalized after.
    newString = str.replace(before, afterCap);
}
```

The second else-if statement can be translated to just else, turning your code into this:

```
// If before is capitalized,
if (before[0].toUpperCase() === before[0]) {
    // Replace with capitalized after.
    newString = str.replace(before, afterCap);
} else {
    // If before not-capitalized,
    // Replace with lowercase after.
    newString = str.replace(before, after);
}
```

you could reduce it even more by using the ternary conditional assignment operator

```
 newString = str.replace(before, 
                         before[0].toUppercase() === before[0] ? afterCap : after 
             );
```

Comment: `toUpperCase` can return the empty string, e.g. `"".toUpperCase()`.

Comment: An empty string is also not truthy.

Comment: @Oriol thanks was focusing on the actual given code rather than in general but should have noted that, updated for clarity

Answer (score 1):

This is how you check if a given string (or char) is uppercase

```
function isUpperCase(str) {
    return str === str.toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: JS doesn't have chars. They are just strings of length 1.

Comment: @smerny it looks like it's what he checks for

Comment: @Oriol exactly, I just didn't want to make any confusion since he is checking if the first letter is uppercase